Как сделать анти спам в боте aiogram
Можно ли сделать в aiogram3 если пользователей отправил 3 команды сразу, то блокнуть его на 2 секунды

Приведите в вопросе ваши попытки решения и что у вас не получилось. Здесь за вас ничего делать не будут.

На 2 секунды нельзя. Минимум 30 секунд

Пример anti spam мидлваря, настройте его под свои нужды.
from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled
import asyncio
from aiogram import types
from loader import *


def rate_limit(limit: float, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, 'throttling_rate_limit', limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, 'throttling_key', key)
        return func

    return decorator


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()

        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, 'throttling_rate_limit', self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            await self.message_throttled(message, t)
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def message_throttled(self, message: types.Message, throttled: Throttled):

        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)

